# How to Filter New Accounts - Large Data Volumes?

Tags: record-type, largedatavolumes, account-management

My business partners are adding in 1000000 new records into Salesforce and they want to document at a location level as well
as keep the current data documentation at an org level untouched with no crossover.

It is the same profiles documenting the same items just at a different level.

The business doesn't want the new groups to show with the old records in search or reporting.  I spoke to IT and they told be to build a different account record type and create an app with different page layouts tied to that record type, but that isn't working.

I thought about creating a custom Object with master detail relationship and hiding account in the app, but I'm not sure if that would work.  Any ideas on how to parse these new records to separate them from the existing ones in the same org plus being documented by the same users?

**Edit**

*From comments:*

Currently our users document and track everything at an org (account?) level. We only have 1 record for that org. Now they want to document both at an org level and at a location level as well, but track the location data separate of the org level data. Because of how our consultants initially designed the system, we can't use a (account?) hierarchy for this. Location would be the master in my new object (to account?) is what I was thinking.

Comment: Welcome to SF.SE. Can you clarify what you mean by "same profiles documenting same items at different level"? Also, if you create a new app for this, you'd still have a lookup to account. What would be the Master in the M-D relationship? Location? That part of your question is unclear.

Comment: Currently our user document and track everything at an org level and we only have 1 record for that org.   Now they want to document both at an org level and now document at a location level as well but track the location data separate of the org level data.    We cant use hierarchy based on how our consultants initially designed the system unfortunately either Location would be the master in my new object is what I was thinking.

Comment: please use [edit] to amend your question rather than using comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume that by "org" you're referring to an organization you do business with that's an `account record` in your Salesforce Instance. Using a custom object called "Location" as the Master in a M-D relationship with `Account` doesn't seem to *me* to be good solution to your issue.

Unless the `Location` object related the parent account to it's children, it wouldn't seem to serve any purpose. Unless you create a hierarchy of "Location records", it would seem to require two custom objects to relate them properly; one that looks up to the parents (or "Master" accounts) and another that looks up to the children (or "child location" accounts). In doing that, there'would be no need for a M-D relationship, yet, you'd still be creating the same type of hierarchy relationship between the Parent Account and it's Child Accounts as exists in a M-D.

That having been said, although I don't know the details of your implementation, I see no reason why you can't implement the Parent-Child account hierarchy if you put some planning into it by first importing all of the Parent accounts which will be assigned new Salesforce Ids when you do (use any existing Id as an external Id). After import, export the newly created Ids from those accounts in a CSV file and assign them to the `Parent Account` field as appropriate to the other accounts before you import them. Upon import, the relationship will be established for you.

Another alternative, which may fit what you want to do instead of using parenting, is to use the `Account Site` field to relate the unique locations. However, in doing this, all related accounts would need to have the same `Name` (each with unique Ids). It would be the `Account Site` field that distinguishes one location from another, not the `Name` of the Account. Again, this would require planning and preparation before importing the the accounts.

For more, see these references in Salesforce Help: [Considerations and Guidelines for Using Account Hierarchies in Salesforce Classic](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=account_parent_classic.htm&type=0&language=en_US), [Guidelines for Creating Accounts](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=account_add.htm&type=0), and [Account Fields](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=account_fields.htm&type=0&language=en_US).

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I'll test out what you suggested to see if either might work for us.

Comment: You're welcome and thanks for posting on SFSE. Community etiquette is to upvote well thought out questions and answers if you have sufficient reputation. If this post leads you to solving your issue, please help the rest of the community by marking it as having answered your question. See [Someone Answers](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) for more.